# Visual Studio 2010: Positioning an ASP NavigationMenu control

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

I've positioned `<div>` tags before. I always prefer `absolute` positioning.

For this new project, I thought I'd start with a website project in Visual Studio 2010.

Everything seems to be doing what I tell it to do except for the positioning of an asp:Menu control called `NavigationMenu` that Visual Studio placed in my Site.Master file.

In the GUI, the `NavigationMenu` indicates that it's `CssClass` property is "menu", but in the "Styles/Site.css" file that Visual Studio created, I do not see anything defined under either `Menu` or `NavigationMenu`. There is a `div.menu` definition, that I have set to use `left: 0px;`, but `NavigationMenu` continues to *try my patience( by centering itself inside the `<div>` tag that I have placed it in.

So far, I have tried this:

```
div.menu {
  left: 0px; height:400px;top:100px;width:150px;
}
```

this:

```
div.menu {
  left: 0px; height:400px;top:100px;width:150px;vertical-align:top;
}
```

and this:

```
div.menu {
  left: 0px; height:400px;top:100px;width:150px;vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

It does not matter. The `NavigationMenu` continues to float in the middle of the `<div>` tag.

I have not renamed this asp:Menu control. Is is the "out of the box" version that Visual Studio 2010 creates.

Could someone tell me where the positioning definitions are for this control before I go mad?

**Comment:** forgot to add this:

```
div {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had some problems styling asp elements before. The resolution for me was to place the styles directly in the asp element definition.

something like.

```
<asp:menu runat="server" style="left:0px;height:400px;top:100px;width:150px;" /></asp:Menu>
```

The problem may also be occuring as you need to set the position property for both the div and the menu.

```
#div {
  position: relative;
}
.menu {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   height:400px;
   top:100px;
   width:150px;
}
```

This is a good read for examples of CSS positioning.

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Thanks Rupert! I stuck the `style` in the `asp:menu` tag and all is well.

Comment: No Problem. I found you will need to do this method when styling many asp elements.